# Understanding /var/log/auth.log - Confusion about "pam_unix" and "polkit"

Tags: ssh, authentication, log, pam

I am having an hard time understanding some lines inside my auth.log file from Ubuntu. Can you help me breaking down the pieces of this one?

```
pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
```

pkexec is the executable that launches pam_unix (?) pam_unix is a system call used to authenticate the user (?) I can't figure out what polkit-1 session is

What does session opened mean? That someone has tried to login or someone has succeeded to login?

Is there any way to investigate from where this request of authentication came from? More log lines below:

Also any resource to learn more about this would be helpful, I have already checked a lot of websites, so maybe you can suggest a sys admin book that might explain this?

```
Jun  4 06:30:36 laptop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun  4 06:30:36 laptop pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun  4 06:30:36 laptop pkexec[26293]: giulia: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/giulia] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jun  4 07:03:36 laptop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun  4 07:03:36 laptop pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun  4 07:03:36 laptop pkexec[26507]: giulia: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/giulia] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jun  4 07:56:50 laptop unix_chkpwd[27106]: password check failed for user (giulia)
Jun  4 07:56:50 laptop compiz: pam_unix(unity:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=1001 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=giulia
Jun  4 08:24:36 laptop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun  4 08:24:36 laptop pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun  4 08:24:36 laptop pkexec[27821]: giulia: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/giulia] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
```

Answer (score 1):

Polkit is a system for privilage excelation, similar to that of PAM, although the exact mechanics vary between the two. `pkexec` is a command that exposes a `sudo` style command for running commands as another user (usually root). Polkit is somewhat complicates, doesn't quite make sense, and is a little difficult to wrap one's head around, but from what I
understand, `pkexec` is calling PAM to verify the users credentials before passing that info onto the polkit daemon, along with what is to be executed (I never said this makes sense).

`pam_unix` is a module for PAM, which is the defacto standard for authencating (not necessarily authorizing) a user. PAM is a library used by an application (such as sudo, sshd, the polkit daemon, the login screen (display manager) for your desktop enviroment, etc) to check if a user exists, and if the given credentials are valiad. pam_unix is one if many modules, which checks the given credentials against the `/etc/password` and `/etc/shadow` files.